# Can I use Enum as return type in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Can I convert enums values to class properties dynamically and use that in below code

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DynamicEnumType>(result)
```

Here actually DynamicEnumType is enum but I want assign result to dynamically created class based on enum.

Comment: Enum under the hood is just a number (or byte when defined so), so you can just cast it to the desired type. If it exists as string in your response, then just use `Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(resultString)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, for example the below works:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}

public class TestClass
{
    public TestEnum TestProp { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var exampleJson = "{TestProp:'Value2'}";
    var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(exampleJson);
    Console.WriteLine(deserializedObj.TestProp);
}
```